# CollectionViewCell change color on didSelectItemAt and on didDeselectItemAt

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm showing a collection view so the user's could choose categories and subsequently I'm populating the TableView.

The problem is, when the collection cell is out of view the didDeselectItemAt function is not responding.

Here is my code:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)?.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground
    let category = catgories[indexPath.row]
    setCategory(category: category)
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}
```

Comment: can attach picture ?

Comment: I will shortly, for now, for example: if I chose the first one, scroll to the end and chose other one, both cells will be colored (collection is horizontal)

Answer (score 0):

That's because the cells inside the collectionView are reused , you need to create array model and keep track of every cell color and assign them inside `cellForRowAt` , this

```
collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

be `nil`  when the indexPath is completely out of screen and to verify do this

```
collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

and the app will crash

Comment: Do you have an example?